# Memory Checker detected 1 access violations. error = access violation on load (global memory)

Tags: cuda

When I debugging my code this error shown when cursor goto :
`scoreMatrix[0] = dev_matrix[a]+similarityScore(dev_strA[a-1],dev_strB[b-1]);`
 and repeatedly shown for 
`scoreMatrix[1], scoreMatrix[2], scoreMatrix[3]`

```
__global__ void kernel_ScoreMatrix(char *dev_strA, char *dev_strB, int *dev_matrix, int *dev_array, int *array_length)
{
int x= blockIdx.x;
int y=blockIdx.y;
int m = COLUMNS*y + x;

for (int i=0; i<*(array_length); i++)
    if (m==dev_array[i]){

int a = COLUMNS*(y-1) + (x-1);
int b= COLUMNS*(y-1) + (x);
int c= COLUMNS*(y) + (x-1);

int scoreMatrix[4];

scoreMatrix[0] = dev_matrix[a]+similarityScore(dev_strA[a-1],dev_strB[b-1]);
scoreMatrix[1] = dev_matrix[b]+GAP;
scoreMatrix[2] = dev_matrix[c]+GAP;
scoreMatrix[3] = 0;
dev_matrix[m] = findMax(scoreMatrix,4);
    }
}
```

this a picture of problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of the variable `a` equals zero so the statement `dev_strA[a-1]` causes an access violation.